# Django view doesn't display model value - Django 1.5

Tags: django, view, model

I created a very simple example code using Django, but cannot get model value to be displayed on my page:

----------------------------- home/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Home(models.Model):
    msg = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, msg):
        home = cls(msg=msg)
        # do something with the book
        return home

home = Home.create("Hello World!")
```

------------------------------------home/views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from project.models import Home

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    model = Home
    template_name = 'home/index.html'
```

------------------------------------------ templates/home/index.html

```
{{ home.msg }}
this is a test page. I am expecting to see this....
```

------------------------------------------- urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Home pagetentacl.urls
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home/index.html')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

-------------------------------------- result page on browser:

this is a test page. I am expecting to see this....

---

I don't want to have DB access for my example. I want my model returns "hello world" string. home.msg on index.html doesn't return anything. What is missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving the template an instance of `Home`. You need to create one and pass it to the template as a Context, in the form `{'msg': msg}`.

EDIT: Adding some code

First of all, you should create your instance of `home` in your view. I've never used `TemplateViews`, so I'm going to use a regular view method instead.

```
def IndexView(request):
    home=Home.create("Hello World!")

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'home': home},)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel rightly points out, you're not giving your template an instance of `Home` to work with.

If you want to use class-based views, subclass `TemplateView` and override `get_context_data()`:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "home/index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): 
        context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["home"] = Home.create("Hello World!")
        return context
```

And make sure your `urls.py` is using `IndexView.as_view()` - your version above is just referencing the generic `TemplateView`.

The fact that you added a `model` field to your subclass of `TemplateView` makes me think you're confusing it with `DetailView`. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/) for the difference.

Comment: Thanks Kevin and Daniel. I am just started with Django project and new with the framework... Problem is fixed... I can see my text on the page now...